# Bash: using variables in sed, double quotes cause error

Tags: bash, sed

I need to replace a block of code in a file using sed and variables. Here're examples which generally do not work for me:

```
confSearch="\"host\": \"localhost\""
confReplacement="\"host\": \"10.20.30.40\""

sed -i "s|$confSearch|$confReplacement|g" "$configFile"
```

However, without variable it works:

```
sed -i "s|\"host\": \"localhost\"|$confReplacement|g" "$configFile"
```

This one does search but replaces, of course, only the variable name:

```
sed -i 's|\"host\": \"localhost\"|$confReplacement|g' "$configFile'
```

Putting a variable into double or single quotes also does nothing for me. RedHat.

Would be grateful for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example doesn't use `$confSearch` - is this a typo in your question, or is this the source of the error? Your code works correctly for me:

```
$ cat f
"host": "localhost"
$ confSearch="\"host\": \"localhost\""
$ confReplacement="\"host\": \"10.20.30.40\""
$ sed "s|$confSearch|$confReplacement|g" f
"host": "10.20.30.40"
```

In order to avoid escaping so many double quotes, you could define your variables using single quotes - double quotes are not special when enclosed in single quotes.

```
$ confSearch='"host": "localhost"'
$ confReplace='"host": "10.20.30.40"'
$ sed "s|$confSearch|$confReplacement|g" f
"host": "10.20.30.40"
```

Comment: It was a typo. You're right about escaping so many double quotes, thanks. I also know that it should work, but it doesn't.

Comment: Gosh, it finally worked after I've changed wrapping double quotes to single in variables. Have absolutely no idea why, checked the syntax of variables many times. Thank you very much.